# building portal / blog like in iwannabemom.com using joomla

Tags: php, content-management-system, joomla, joomla1.5, blogs

I need some recommendations ... I was asked to built a web portal/blog that looks like http://iwannabemom.com/(they use wordpress)

the reason i am using joomla because i have some components that i need to implement on joomla instead of using wordpress.

what is the components for (joomla 1.5):
1. top news (can be scrolled). I know there are Gavick, it is good ... but I need second options for that
2. thumbnail image for each articles. Joomla has no thumbnail for article modules .. sad :(
3. comment system. should I use Disqus (disqus.com) or using jomcomment. About Disqus, is it good and reliable services ?
4. Tag hierarchy ... any good recommendations ?
5. I hate Joomla Media Manager and Joomla Text Editor (TinyMCE) because I cannot choose directly from media manager (i have to type the full url for images). Any good recommendations ?

Comment: wow, badly worded question :s

Answer (score 0):

Please split up your question into separate owns that somebody can answer. It's easier for people to answer a specific question than a general question that you ask.

For point 4:
Jacek Zielinski's JTags is a good one for a Tag hierarchy.